# Browser sends RST to shoutcast stream on page refresh when using HTML5 <audio> tag

Tags: html, audio, stream

I am working on an application that parses metadata from shoutcast/icecast streams (in MP3 format) and relays the audio sans-metadata to a web page with an  tag

Architecture:

Windows 7 w/Python 2.7

localhost:8080 -> Tornado application serves audio player on / and metadata on /metadata

localhost:8000 -> Python socket relays parsed stream w/NO HTTP headers, only stream data

...

other sockets connect to discogs/gracenote apis to collect additional metadata

Using an audio tag like this:

```
<audio id="stream" preload="none" src="http://localhost:8000"></audio>
```

I would expect to be able to hear the stream in my browser and to limit the browser to sending only a single connection to my server. It DOES work, but when I refresh the page, the browser will begin to buffer the stream as usual and then suddenly cancel the connection by sending a RST packet.

On the python backend, I get the following error in the main loop of my socket handling:

```
error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

That socket handling looks like this, basically it parses the metadata from the shoutcast stream and sends mp3 data back to the client:

```
    while self.running:
        data = ''
        for i in range(bytes):
            data += self.s_stream_in.recv(1)
        print "sending..."
        self.conn.sendall(data)
        length = ord(self.s_stream_in.recv(1)) * 16
        if length > 0:
            data = self.s_stream_in.recv(length)
            in_queue.put(data)
        bytes = metaint
```

I tried a variety of things in the python backend code to prevent these RSTs from happening, including setting all sorts of socket flags and ensuring that no firewall/antivirus was interfering with the connection. Then I decided to use the original source stream in the audio tag to see if it has the same issue. The semicolon is added to tell shoutcast to send the stream and not the web interface.

```
<audio id="stream" preload="none" src="http://streamerepsilon.jazz.fm:8000/;"></audio>
```

Surprise, surprise! The original stream exhibits the same behavior: the initial connection to the mp3 stream works fine, but when the page is refreshed a RST packet is sent to the stream server. I have observed this behavior in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I filed a bug report with chromium developers here:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=281710